# What's the order returned by getAccountTransactions?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I was expecting it would return ordered by postedDate, but that does not seem to be case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just the order of retrieval from the website(FI).AggCat service doesn't change that order.

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever seen the order for chase bank credit card? It's completely random.